# Change y-axis scale - FacetGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, facet

I cannot work out how to change the scale of the y-axis. My code is:

```
grid = sns.catplot(x='Nationality', y='count', 
                   row='Age', col='Gender', 
                   hue='Type',
                   data=dfNorthumbria2, kind='bar', ci='No')
```

[image: it currently looks like this]

I wanted to just go up in full numbers rather than in .5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

I just now found this [tutorial](https://cduvallet.github.io/posts/2018/11/facetgrid-ylabel-access) the probably easiest solution will be the following:

```
grid.set(yticks=list(range(5)))
```

From the help of `grid.set`

```
Help on method set in module seaborn.axisgrid:
set(**kwargs) method of seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid instance
    Set attributes on each subplot Axes.
```

---

Since seaborn is build on top of matplotlib you can use [yticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) from plt

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.yticks(range(5))
```

However this changed only the yticks of the upper row in my mockup example.
For this reason you probably want to change the y ticks based on the axis with `ax.set_yticks()`. To get the axis from your `grid` object you can implemented a list comprehension as follows:

```
[ax[0].set_yticks(range(0,150,5) )for ax in grid.axes]
```

A full replicable example would look like this (adapted from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html))

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
grid = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind",
                row="diet", data=exercise)
# plt.yticks(range(0,150,5)) # Changed only one y-axis

# Changed y-ticks to steps of 20 
[ax[0].set_yticks(range(0,150,20) )for ax in grid.axes]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sam I am glad that I could help. Could accept the answer if you think it solved the issue for you? This can help to make the solution more visible to others searching for similar problem